# Wordpress file permissions for editing on local Ubuntu development machine

Tags: permissions

I've seen a couple of solutions on this site that solved some permission problems, however, they seem that they create others, at least for me. My setup is a local wordpress installation on Ubuntu 14.04.

For example: when I want to install a plugin from within my wordpress admin area, I used to get asked to enter my FTP details. Surfing for an answer, I found that changing your `user:group` to `www-data:www-data` would solve it, and indeed it did.

However, upon making that change, my files stopped being writable from any editor. I tried adding my current user name `nasser` to the `www-data` group (I did this with `sudo adduser nasser www-data`) and even changed all of my file permissions to `775`, but to no avail.

So now, I'm switching back and forth between owners/groups if I want to add a plugin or theme while editing. <strike>I could settle for simply downloading a plugin/theme and unzipping it manually into `wp-content/plugins` or `/themes`</strike> Even unzipping a theme/plugin and manually copying it to the appropriate location would require a permission change.

Any help would be much appreciated. If I missed any details, or was unclear, please let me know.

Comment: If the answer has been helpful consider accepting it - if you need more information read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

I'm too working on Ubuntu, personally I'm setting things up like this:

```
sudo chown -R nasser /path/to/your/wordpress/root/
sudo chgrp -R www-data /path/to/your/wordpress/root/
sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/your/wordpress/root/
```

I **only** do this on my local development machine for convenience and a smoother work-flow. One more thing to note, I've moved the `www` directory into the `home` directory, symlinking from `/var/www/` to `/home/user/www/`, which is convenient, but shouldn't be necessary.

Do **not** forget to revert this back before deploying, for this do at the very least this:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /path/to/your/wordpress/root/
sudo chgrp -R www-data /path/to/your/wordpress/root/
// the last two lines can be combined like:
// sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/wordpress/root/
sudo find /path/to/your/wordpress/root/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 644
// the last line could also be done like this:
// sudo find /path/to/your/wordpress/root/ -type f -exec chmod {} 644 \;
sudo find /path/to/your/wordpress/root/ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 755
// the last line could also be done like this:
// sudo find /path/to/your/wordpress/root/ -type d -exec chmod {} 755 \;
sudo chmod 600 /path/to/your/wordpress/root/wp-config.php
```

You might of course have other wishes for your file permissions, more about that in the codex articles [Changing File Permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) and [Hardening WordPress - File Permissions](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/#file-permissions).

Comment: With these settings you cannot update plugins via wp-admin due to ftp connection notice. You must use a group and user `www-data`. Some say "Solved!" but the problem is that when you later create files on your server, these files are not created like `www-data`, but as the user you are logged in to

Comment: @kanlukasz I stated in my answer that you have to change it back for the deployment on the server.

Comment: Yes, of course, but in the development environment, you may also want to update your plugins and you can't. Of course we can do this with `wp-cli`, but that's another story.